# dynamically rendered components with context and react.memo does not update state accordingly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to render components based on a JSON document. I am trying to solve this with hooks and context. Because the components have a state and I don't want to rerender all components when one state of a component changes, I use React.memo to prevent re-renders. And consequently, I lift all states up, so I can manage the state in the top-level hook and pass everything down as props.

Now, when I want to change the state from inside a component, React.memo seems to memorize the old state, and the state is not updated as intended.
Because it is a little hard to explain, I provided an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-borg-z55ie). If you click on the different colored divs you will directly see the problem. I also provide some console output to show that only the klicked component re-renders.

How can I solve the problem that only the klicked component re-renders while taking into account the newly updated state?

Also, here is the full code for `App.tsx` (same as in code sandbox)

```
import * as React from "react";

type DivTemplate = {
  [key: string]: {
    type: "green" | "red" | "blue";
  };
};

type DivDoc = { [key: string]: number };

const TripleDivObj: DivTemplate = {
  green_div: {
    type: "green"
  },
  red_div: {
    type: "red"
  },
  blue_div: {
    type: "blue"
  }
};

type ColorDivProps = {
  id: string;
  color: "green" | "red" | "blue";
  count: number;
  incrementValue: () => void;
};

const ColorDiv = React.memo(
  (props: ColorDivProps) => {
    console.log(`Hook re-render ${props.color}. Value ${props.count}`);

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          background: props.color,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          fontSize: 32,
          color: "white",
          display: "grid",
          placeItems: "center"
        }}
        onClick={() => props.incrementValue()}
      >
        {props.count}
      </div>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.count === nextProps.count
);

function TripleDiv() {
  const { getCount, incrementValue } = useTripleDivHookContext();
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100vw",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around"
      }}
    >
      {Object.entries(TripleDivObj).map(([id, value]) => {
        return (
          <ColorDiv
            key={id}
            id={id}
            color={value.type}
            count={getCount(id)}
            incrementValue={() => incrementValue(id)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const TripleDivHookContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<
  typeof useTripleDiv
> | null>(null);

const useTripleDivHookContext = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(TripleDivHookContext);
  if (value === null) throw Error("Context is null");
  return value;
};

const useTripleDiv = () => {
  const _divState: DivDoc = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(TripleDivObj)) {
    _divState[key] = 0;
  }
  const [divState, setDivState] = React.useState<DivDoc>(_divState);

  const incrementValue = (id: string) => {
    console.log(`about to increment: ${id}`);
    console.log(`state: ${JSON.stringify(divState)}`);
    if (id in divState) {
      console.log(`increment ${id}`);
      setDivState({ ...divState, [id]: divState[id] + 1 });
    }
  };

  function getCount(id: string) {
    if (id in divState) return divState[id];
    return 0;
  }

  return { getCount, incrementValue };
};

function HookBasedDivs() {
  const hook = useTripleDiv();

  return (
    <TripleDivHookContext.Provider value={hook}>
      <TripleDiv />
    </TripleDivHookContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hooks</h1>
      <HookBasedDivs />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it fully, but it works when you replace line 101

```
setDivState({ ...divState, [id]: divState[id] + 1 });
```

with

```
setDivState((prevDivState) => {
  return { ...prevDivState, [id]: prevDivState[id] + 1 };
});
```

Comment: Passing in a function to `setState` is the recommended format to write setState calls that depend on the previous state. This is because the state update is asynchronous. You can see this in the [React docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)